# How to flash a lot of devices like Raspberry Pi (More than 1000)?

Tags: arm, flash

Our devices based on ARM and eMMC memory on board, and how mass flash our soft on this devices? (More than 1000 devices)

Comment: eMMC programmer - before soldering, maybe?

Comment: Either get the eMMC preprogrammed or build a programming rig.

Comment: Like a rasberry pi, that would make a huge difference. A raspi you can throw different card in it, other devices aren't so simple. You need to specify the device.

Comment: @laptop2d: Unless you needed to program the GPU.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Yeah, the OP needs to specify *what they intend to program*. Right now the question says "How to flash a lot of devices like Raspberry Pi" There are a lot of devices *like a rasp pi*

Comment: In the past we had a computer with a few USB hubs. The computer monitors DBUS and detects newly plugged in devices and identifies it, then run a script to flash it, at the end of the script it shuts down the device. So you just go check the rig every once a while and removed finished devices and plug in new ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In manufacturing. You would provide the code to be flashed on the on board flash prior to assembly, or it would be loaded through a jtag jig after assembly.

For an end user, there are options like getting SD cards manufactured with your software on it, then loading those on the devices yourself (or a middle man service that you pay to do this), or using software like PXE network booting that will install it for you after configuration. Different devices have different methods. The RPI 2 needs a sd card with config to boot to network boot, the 3 requires a one time config, and the 1 cannot natively network boot.